# Дочерний класс со своим конструктором

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
<div id="container"></div>



class Parent {
  constructor(){
    this.elem = document.createElement("span");
    this.elem.textContent= " Имя";
    container.appendChild(this.elem);
  };

   func = function(){
      console.log(this.elem.textContent);
   };

};



class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(){
    this.elem = document.createElement("span");
    this.elem.textContent= " Фамилия";
    container.appendChild(this.elem);
  }
}
```

При попытке создать экземпляр дочернего класса возникает ошибка:

```
child = new Child(); 
child.func();
//Uncaught ReferenceError: Must call super constructor 
//in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
```

Проблема заключалась в том, что нужно вызвать `super();` в конструкторе потомка

```
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.elem = document.createElement("span");
        this.elem.textContent= " Фамилия";
        container.appendChild(this.elem);
  }
}
```

Но тогда При создании `new Child` создается как элемент "Имя" так и элемент "Фамилия". Мне нужно чтобы у потомка был свой конструктор, но чтобы он наследовал методы родителя. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(){
    super();
    //this.elem = document.createElement("span");
    this.elem.textContent = " Фамилия";
    //container.appendChild(this.elem);
  }
}
```

---

> Сделать полностью собственный конструктор для потомка

Смысл этой фразы от меня ускользает.

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.elem = null;
  }

   func = function() {
      console.log(this.elem.textContent);
   }
}

class Child_Name extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.elem = document.createElement("span");
    this.elem.textContent= " Имя";
    container.appendChild(this.elem);
  }
}

class Child_Surname extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.elem = document.createElement("span");
    this.elem.textContent = " Фамилия";
    container.appendChild(this.elem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Это я привел для примера, там у родителя несколько другая внутренняя структура чем у потомка. Сделать полностью собственный конструктор для потомка стандартными средствами не получится?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov конструктор родителя надо вызвать в люмо случае. Единственный совет - не делайте никаких операций, которые могут вызвать сайд-эффект, в конструкторе. Конструктор - для инициализации первоночальных значений.